# Is there any way to find out flask application is running properly on aws ec2?

Tags: ubuntu, flask, amazon-ec2, uwsgi

I am trying to deploying my simple flask application on aws ec2 instance. However i am experiencing some troubles.

Problem:

- I set inbound settings that allows tcp request from my local device. (8080 Port)
- Also, i set inbound settings that allows http request from my local device.
- I used `uWSGI` to deploy flask app.
- When i send http request to ec2 instance, i get response without any problems that apache2 serves.
- By the way, i can not get a response from port 8080.

These are what I tried:

- executed `uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:8080 --master -w server:app` to open server. `server:app` is my module name.
- executed `curl http://localhost:8080` at terminal of ec2 instance, and i get response of html that contains my flask app produce.
- executed `sudo netstat -tlnp` to check `uWSGI` is running well. And the result is this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34935         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3214/uwsgi

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      310/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3214/uwsgi

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      548/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1421/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      548/sshd: /
```

- executed `tcping <instance ip address> 8080` , and there is no response.

Finally, i paste my aws ec2 inbound settings for who is suspicious to my inbound settings. (that korean means user casual tcp)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I execute command `nc -l 8080` to check ec2 gets request well.
Then, netcat noticed me request comes well. It meant there is a problem at application layer. After all i found my mistake:

This problem happens because of "host address".
I exectued `uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:8080 --master -w server:app` to open server. By the way 127.0.0.1 is loopback address which means aws ec2 instance itself.